# How to find unique value by combination of column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one reporting table from which I have to prepare one report.

say for suppose I have name A,B,C,D,H and its different code I have to calculate Unique value of A  here in 2.

Like wise I have to calculate for A+B , A+B+C, B+C, A+B like that

```
NAME   CODE 
A   10
A   10
A   10
A   10
A   10
A   10
A   11
B   10
B   10
C   10
C   11
D   10
D   10
H   11
```

I am achieving this with union all for now

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be great. WE have *some* of your data, but not all of it, and we don't know what the desired result of `A+B` is (at a guess, `91`?).

Comment: A+B Means Unique code of A and and B here we have 2  and D+H  means unique code of D and H like wise

Comment: But there are 7 rows for `A`, of which there are 2 distinct values. So "`A+B = 10 + 11 + 10 = 31`"??? Again, expected result are needed here.

Comment: No A+B means select count(distinct code) from table1 where name in ('A','B')

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select distinct code from <tablename> where name in ('A','B');
```

You can add or remove the contents inside () as per your need.

If you want the count of the records, you can use declare a variable and assign @@ROWCOUNT to it.